# Is there an efficient algorithm for computing most common sub-anagrams?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

What is an efficient algorithm and data structure for computing the most common sub-anagrams in the English language? Sub anagrams are words that can be formed from all or some of the letters of other words. So "bar" is a sub-anagram of "brave".

Specifically I am looking for an algorithm more efficient than nested iteration through every word in the dictionary.

The output of the algorithm should be a list of all sub-anagrams sorted by # of times they appear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: You could restructure your dictionary. E.g. a hash map with the sorted characters of a word as key and a list of all words having those letters as value. Then you just have to build all possible combinations and read the words from the dictionary. E.g. for ara you look up a, r, aa, ar and aar.

Comment: The most common sub-anagrams according to this description surely are `a` or `I`. In other words, you are just searching for the shortest English words. Refining the task description is strongly recommended…

Comment: @Holger, I agree that in full English those are good contenders (I'd also be interested in `he` given how `the` is popular) but if this is some competitive programming task (which it can easily be), the dictionary can be artificial an much smaller than the full English and also without single-character words. Obviously this is just a guess and generally this is a good advice.

Comment: I think the trie is the beginning of a good idea. Maybe iterating through a-z, then aa-zz, then aaa-zzz, aaaa-zzzz, etc. Each time you iterate, you check for words containing the letters, and as you successively iterate, you could create a node network (trie) of words and their parent-anagrams.